# How to jump in a dropdown ul li big list by pressing a letter?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In a rails 3 app i'am using twitter bootstrap. I have a view i'm generating a big dropdown list allowing people to select a name. Using ajax when you click on a name, the name appears on another list and the dropdown menu is not closed by the page refreshing.

The list is containing at least 500 names. It's not to difficult to seek a name inside but to improve user experience i'm trying to make a kind of shortcut. I want to make jump in the dropdown list when pressing a letter char.

If i use an:

```
<select>
 <option> name </option>
 <option> ... </option>
</select>
```

The list make the trick, you can press "z" and you fall in the end of the menu. But the select/option method is more appropriate to a form, and i have to put a validation button to send the data and i loose my ajax advantage.

I make a try with autocomplete method using jquery but my users tell me that they prefer the list in the case they are not sure of the orthography of the name.

I'm looking into combobox to improve the dropdown behaviour but i think it's gonna be like the select list and i have to make a validation button. And i don't want my users to repeat the open the list, click, send, refresh reopen the list ...

Is there a way to make the jump in the list by pressing a letter?
Do you have suggestions for the users which have to find a name in a long list, how can i improve their navigation?

Thanks

EDIT:

The actual dropdown list looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% participants.each do |p| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "#{p.first-name} #{p.last-name}",
                  activity_activity_items_path(
                    @activity,
                    activity_item:{
                                    activity_itemable_id: p.id,
                                    activity_itemable_type: p.class.name
                                    } ),
                  method: :post,
                  remote: true %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a jquery plugin with all these features, instead of creating from scratch. Something like the `chosen` plugin or `select2` should do the job, as they have events on selecting the itens, searching features and stuff.

Chosen: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

**UPDATE:**

Try creating the select normally, and firing an ajax call on option change.

```
$('#your_select').change(function() {
  // Make your ajax call here, update what you want.
});
```

This way you can remove the need for inserting a link inside the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll give a try with select2 (which is impressive). I see their remote option too that seems easy to implement.

Comment: Finally i give a quick try with chosen. The generated list and search behaviour are perfect but the generated <select> cannot embed a link. So  without a customization of js i can't retrieve my old ajax call that was updating the document by adding a name. I'm editing my question to give more details on the actual dropdown list.

Comment: Well, in this case i believe it is better to just create a normal select, with labels and values and fire the ajax call on the select change event.

Comment: But your first suggestion is really good for the user of the application. I'll spend some time to implement select2 with the ajax call on the change event. I'm reading their docs. I also find a youtube tutorial (www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9yvKdYYKqQ) that might be helping to implement select2.

Answer (score 0):

Another (pretty nice) option is to use a typeahead: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

> Inspired by twitter.com's autocomplete search functionality,
>   typeahead.js
>   is a flexible JavaScript library that provides a strong foundation for
>   building robust typeaheads.
>
> The typeahead.js library consists of 2 components: the suggestion
>   engine, Bloodhound, and the UI view, Typeahead. The suggestion engine
>   is responsible for computing suggestions for a given query. The UI
>   view is responsible for rendering suggestions and handling DOM
>   interactions. Both components can be used separately, but when used
>   together, they can provide a rich typeahead experience

Since you're making a single selection and want to be able to search options this i feel would be your best bet.

It's very simple to setup too... just bind your array of names and configure.